# How to create multi armature animations?

Tags: animation, armature, actions

I have a character armature and mesh that I want to duplicate. I then want to use both copies for an animated action in which they are entangled together. At a high level this would be a grapple, or wrestling animation e.g. two characters grappling and wrestling around. What is a workflow for building this kind of animation? As far as I know blenders actions and key frames are bound to a singular armature. How can I build like a multi armature animations?